# Visual Studio выдаёт ошибку C4996 при попытке скомпилировать этот проект

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    char strHello[256] = "hello"; 
    char strWorld[256] = " world";
    strcat (strHello, strWorld);//я так же обратил внимание и на другие команды(strcpy,strcmp);
    cout << strHello << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: можете добавить скриншот ошибки?

Comment: @Grundy Чему вы учите, никаких скриншотов, только текст!

Comment: @Cerbo, иногда картинка может быть более информативной

Comment: GCC компилирует без ошибок.

Comment: @kff для VS это именно ошибка.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Visual C++ рекомендуется использовать функцию `strcat_s`, и другие функции с `_s` на конце. Она принимает размер буфера, по этому при ее использовании не может произойти переполнение буфера.

```
char strHello[256] = "hello"; 
char strWorld[256] = " world";
strcat_s (strHello, sizeof(strHello), strWorld);
// или, для массивов (не указателей) можно не передавать размер:
strcat_s (strHello, strWorld);
```

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что ошибка всё же имеет номер C4996 (а не C4999). Возникает по причине того, что MS считает функцию `strcat` небезопасной (в принципе не безосновательно). Однако, приводить к ошибке (не предупреждению) компиляции это по моему мнению не должно. Тем не менее, чтобы упомянутой ошибки не возникало, достаточно добавить следующую строку в начало исходника:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Comment: Ой извините 4996. 2 ответ правильный.